# Deploy Cassini application with Click Once. How do I copy web application to output?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce, cassini

Is there an easy way to include the output of a Web Application in VS2010.

My goal is to deploy a Cassini based web application with Click Once. To do this I want to take the published version of the Web Application and put it in a directory to be used as content for the Click Once deployment.

Thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck with IIS Express than Cassini. Cassini was never meant for anything other than developer use.

Comment: @vcsjones Cassini works great for what i'm doing. This is a question about getting the files copied over properly when deploying about click once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to publish the website into my desktop application project, set the build action for every item to Content.

Then when deploying with click once it copied the whole site over with the Cassini web server.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce deployment is for client applications, such as WPF, Windows Forms, or console appications.

Having said that, I will tell you that I once wrote a WinForms app for the sole purpose of deploying some files. The app would install the files under the ClickOnce cache and then all it did was copy the files to where they were supposed to really go (MyDocuments\content or something like that), and then it would close. This content was used by another application, so the main application would invoke the url to the content application periodically, and update the content.

I don't know why you would want to deploy a web application with ClickOnce. Seems like it would be better to use the one-click publishing that is built in to Visual Studio for web applications/web sites. You can try the method I've mentioned above, but note that ClickOnce applications must run for a specific user, you have to run the application in order to get an update, and they have no administrative privileges, so if you think it can copy files to the C:\inetpub folder on a server, you're probably dreaming.

Answer (score 0):

Target system will need a web server to run your web application. Therefore you are likely to need a [truly redistributable web server](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst633_Welcome-to-UltiDev-Web-Server-Pro.aspx) and [create at installer for your app](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst660_Creating-Installer-project-bundling-UltiDev-Web-Server-Pro-using-Visual-Studio.aspx) that will include the web server and will have custom install actions to register your application with the web server.